# Validation of Ethereum address on a Form in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input, web3uikit

```
import { Form } from "web3uikit"
import React from "react"

function SellSwapForm({ title, id, onSubmit, extraFields = [] }) {
    const commonFields = [
        {
            name: "NFT Address",
            type: "text",
            inputWidth: "100%",
            key: "nftAddress",
            validation: {
                regExp: /^(0x)[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$/,
                regExpInvalidMessage:
                    "Please enter a valid Ethereum address in the format 0x1234...",
                required: true,
            },
    ]

    const allFields = [...commonFields, ...extraFields]

    return (
        <>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} data={allFields} title={title} id={id} />
        </>
    )
}

export default SellSwapForm
```

I am validating a nftAddress here if the address is not correct i'm getting the regExpInvalidMessage but if the nftAddress is correct i get the message "Deine Eingabe muss mit dem geforderten Feld übereinstimmen"
[this is the message i see when address is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ILPw.jpg)
[this is the rendered content with the inputField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrGIt.jpg)*/}

I only need my own validation like it is above.
I already tried to change the type: "text" to "textarea"
also i tried to set noValidation/novalidation
and i tried to use pattern.
btw. i already asked chatGPT...